# Meaning of localhost:dsf

Tags: python, networking, localhost, netstat, lsof

I am working on a Python Server application that runs on 127.0.0.1 : 555 and I am trying to show the port 555 on lsof, or netstat. My system is macOS and when I type

`sudo lsof | grep localhost`

on terminal, I cannot see the port as localhost:555 instead the end of the output looks like:

`... TCP localhost:dsf (LISTEN)`

Can someone help me about what 'dsf' means and is there any way to show the port 555?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Port numbers <1024 are what are known as "well-known port numbers" (and are usually not able to be instantiated by non-privileged users). I'm not sure where you'd look on macOS, but on Unix machines, there is typically a file in /etc called "services" which provides names for many of those well-known ports. Many utilities use this file to look up names for those ports and display the name rather than the port number. I don't know what 'dsf' is, but it is reserved as such (see [the IANA assignment here](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml?&page=11)). There may be a command line switch to lsof to tell it to always use the port number rather than the name.

As an aside, unless you have a very good reason for doing so, it's generally considered a bad idea to run services on ports < 1024.